# New to CSS - Transitions not working

Tags: html, css, transition

I am throwing together a really quick, really informal website for a school science project. However, the transitions on my list items aren't working when I hover over them. I'd like to apologize in advance for the messy HTML/CSS.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  background-color: #4C99FF;
  height: 10%;
  float: right;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
.nav-button {
  height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#button-one {
  float: left;
}
#button-two {
  float: right;
}
.button-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.nav-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 3%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px padding: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: color .5s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color: .5s;
  -moz-transition: color .5s;
  -moz-transition: background-color: .5s;
}
.nav-item:hover {
  color: #4C99FF;
  background-color: white;
}
#home {
  float: left;
}
#cited {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 header">
      <!--<div class="col-xs-3 nav-button" id="button-one">
        <a href="#"><h1 class="button-text"> Home<span></span> </h1></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 nav-button" id="button-two">
        <h1 class="button-text"> Cited </h1> -->
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <a href="#">
          <li class="nav-item" id="home">Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="nav-item" id="cited">Cited</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could someone help me with this problem? Once again, I am very sorry for the messy code.

Comment: Made it into executable snippet and added body background so we can see the white text. I (on Chrome) can see a transition on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple of things, first you should not use semi-colons for the style attributes, it should be like this instead:

`-webkit-transition: background-color .5s;`

You also shouldn't define transitions separately, it should be comma separated like this:

`-webkit-transition: color .5s, background-color .5s;`

And finally, you should be using the `transition` style attribute aswell, not just the webkit and moz ones.

`transition: color .5s;`